# How to Determine which is your TouchScreen Driver

Tags: 12.04, drivers, hardware, touchscreen

So many unrecognized options come up when typing the command `lsusb`, but how do we determine which one is actually for our specific touchscreen?  Thanks.

```
Bus 001 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub
Bus 002 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub
Bus 003 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub
Bus 004 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0003 Linux Foundation 3.0 root hub
Bus 001 Device 002: ID 8087:0024 Intel Corp. Integrated Rate Matching Hub
Bus 002 Device 002: ID 8087:0024 Intel Corp. Integrated Rate Matching Hub
Bus 003 Device 002: ID 0eef:790a D-WAV Scientific Co., Ltd 
Bus 001 Device 003: ID 147e:2020 Upek 
Bus 001 Device 004: ID 0a5c:21e6 Broadcom Corp. 
Bus 001 Device 005: ID 04f2:b315 Chicony Electronics Co., Ltd
```

Answer (score -1):

Bus 003 Device 002: ID 0eef:790a D-WAV Scientific Co., Ltd  is the driver

Comment: That's not the driver, it's the device.