# Touchscreen on HP Envy x360 is not working with 18.04

Tags: touchscreen, 18.04

When I tried Ubuntu 18.04 LTS on my HP envy x360, the touchscreen of the laptop is not working. How can I fix it?

Comment: Check the answer to this issue: [Right-click on Touchpad not working after update to 18.04 LTS](https://askubuntu.com/q/1028113/29012).

Comment: but my question was not about touch pad it was about touch screen!

Comment: I'm sorry, I missed the tag, and was referring to the content of your title and message text.  I'll vote to reopen your question, as well as research your **Touch Screen** issue.

Comment: This is touch screen details of your exact Laptop model: [Identify the entries of xinput](https://askubuntu.com/q/842670/29012).  This is a question with answer for generic touch screen drivers: [How to Determine which is your TouchScreen Driver](https://askubuntu.com/q/346303/29012).  Which drivers have you installed?

Answer (score 1):

There are two options as for now, both of them presented in following link:
https://bugzilla.kernel.org/show_bug.cgi?id=198715#c14

The first option is to patch kernel manually and install it on your system, I've tested it, it works for my HP Envy x360 15-bq121dx.

Another option is to patch acpi table, people in discussion in link above report successful result. I haven't tried this method yet.

Comment: I have the problem, read that link, not sure what steps would be to get touch working.

Answer (score -3):

Download GNOME Tweaks from Ubuntu Software. Go to the Keyboard & Mouse section. Then go to Mouse, click Emulation, and select Area.